# Prove Differentiability Using Definition of $f(x,y) = 3x^2-xy + y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Prove Differentiability Using Definition of $f(x,y) = 3x^2-xy + y$

The definition I have been given is that :

$$f(x_o + \Delta x, y_o + \Delta y) = f(x_o, y_o)+f_x(x_o,y_o) \Delta x + f_y(x_o,y_o) \Delta y + E_1(\Delta x) + E_2(\Delta y)$$
and we have$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{E_1(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}=0,  \lim\limits_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{E_1(\Delta y)}{\Delta y}=0$$

My attempt:

$$f(x_o + \Delta x, y_o + \Delta y) = f(x_o , y_o ) + \Delta x(6x-y) + \Delta y(-x+1) + 3 \Delta x^2-\Delta x \Delta y =$$$$ f(x_o , y_o ) + \Delta x f_x + \Delta y f_y + 3 \Delta x^2-\Delta x \Delta y  $$

Now obviously $\Delta x \to 0$ then $3 \Delta x^2 /\Delta x \to 0$, but the other limit I am having troubles showing that it goes to zero. Is this the right approach?

Comment: are you sure that your definition does not say the limits should be as $(\Delta x, \Delta y) \to (0,0)\,\,\,?$

Comment: 10:24 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9n0cRmmxkJw this is the definition I am going by. Does it seem wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Function of several variables is differentiable at a point, if it has partial derivatives at point and they are continuous around this point.
$f'_{x} = 6x-y; f'_{y} = -x+1$.
Take point $(x_{0},y_{0}) = (a,b)$.
$f'_{x}(a,b) = 6a-b$
$\lim_{\substack{x\rightarrow0 \\ y\rightarrow 0}} f'_{x}(x,y) = 6a-b$ (now matter what are real numbers a and b)
Thus $f'_{x}(x,y)$ is continuous around any point $(x_{0},y_{0})$.
Make the same procedure for $f'_{y}(x,y)$ to check, that around any point $f'_{y}(x,y)$ is continuous.
I think so.

Comment: Although this is proving differentiability, it isn't proving by the definition directly (or from the first principle)which is what the question calls for. You are citing a downstream theorem.